# TokenMismatchException in my add to cart when i added quantity

Tags: php, session, laravel-5.4, cart

Why I am getting an error in my add to cart when I add some quantities in my cart. Here is my error:
TokenMismatchException

Here is my view:

```
<div class="specs">
    <h4>Details</h4>
    <p>{{ $product_info[0]->description }}</p>
    <label>Quantity</label>                                        
    <div class="quantity">
        <form action="{{ route('prodcart',['id' => $product_info[0]->product_id ]) }}" method="post" id="frmaddcart">
          <input type="number" name="qty" min="1" max="{{ $product_info[0]->quantity }}" step="1" value="1" readonly>
          {{ csrf_field() }}
        </form>
    </div>
    <button id="btnaddCart" class="btn btn-success btn-cart"> ADD TO CART </button>
</div>
```

my jquery submit button:

```
$('#btnaddCart').click(function(){
    $('#frmaddcart').submit();
});
```

in my view I have already put a `CSRF_field()` also my submit button, I already added jquery to submit it in my controller.

Here is my controller:

```
public function addToCart(Request $request, $product_id) 
    {
        $quantity = $request->qty;
        $product = DB::table('products')
        ->select('*')
        ->where(['products.product_id' => $product_id])
        ->first();        
        $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        $cart->add($product, $product->product_id, $quantity);

        $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);
        return redirect()->route('productlist',['id' => $product->subcategory_id ]);
    }
```

Then here is my cart class:

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Cart 
{
    public $items = null;
    public $totalQty = 0;
    public $totalPrice = 0;

    public function __construct($oldCart)
    {
        if($oldCart) {
            $this->items = $oldCart->items;
            $this->totalQty = $oldCart->totalQty;
            $this->totalPrice = $oldCart->totalPrice;
        } 
    }

    public function add($item, $product_id, $quantity) {
        $storedItem = ['qty' => 0, 'price' => $item->price, 'item' => $item];
        if($this->items) {
            if(array_key_exists($product_id, $this->items)) {
                $storedItem = $this->items[$product_id];
            }
        }
        $storedItem['qty'] = $quantity;
        $storedItem['price'] = $item->price * $storedItem['qty'];
        $this->items[$product_id] = $storedItem;
        $this->totalQty++;
        $this->totalPrice += $item->price;

    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the problem when you submits the page. Share how you submit page ?

Comment: @user2486 thanks for your reply sir. my submit is in the button id="btnaddCart" and its in jquery

Answer (score 0):

Put submit button inside form tag and also make it type `submit`

```
 <div class="quantity">
    <form action="{{ route('prodcart',['id' => $product_info[0]->product_id ]) }}" method="post" id="frmaddcart">
      <input type="number" name="qty" min="1" max="{{ $product_info[0]->quantity }}" step="1" value="1" readonly>
      {{ csrf_field() }}
     <button type="submit" id="btnaddCart" class="btn btn-success btn-cart"> ADD TO CART </button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

In case of jquery you need to put extra param `_token` with csrf token value

```
  var _token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
```

Comment: hello sir i updated my question. i put my jquery submit so that you can determine that submitting is not my problem. thanks. please review.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
You dont need jQuery to submit your form.

1. DELETE the following:

   ```
   $('#btnaddCart').click(function(){
       $('#frmaddcart').submit();
   });
   ```
2. Move your submit button inside the `<form>SUBMIT BUTTON HTML HERE</form>`

**You Don't need the following:**

Send along the CSRF token with your ajax request. I assume that your ajax  request looks something like below:

```
$.post(url, {
    productId: productId,
    qty: productQuantity,
    _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}" // add this to send the token along with the request
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer sir, hello . please look at my updated question. i put a jquery for my submit button so that you can determine that submitting is my problem. i dont know why i got TokenMismatchException

Comment: i already put inside my button in form but still error,when i add quantity into 2